# Display property overridden by User Agent Stylesheet

Tags: css

As must be obvious, I am no CSS expert. I have a class

```
.hidden{
 display:hidden
}
```

and a div

```
<div class="hidden">
</div>
```

But the div is not hidden when the page is rendered. When I look at the Computed styles in Chrome, it says the display property was overridden by the user agent stylesheet. Why?

Comment: a good article on hiding elements: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/now-you-see-me/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Css:

```
.hidden {    
    display: none
}
```

is the correct syntax.

Answer (score 6):

If you want the element to not be visible AND not take in any space you should do:

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

However if you want to hide the element, but let it take in space you should do:

```
.hidden { visibility: hidden; }
```

See this [simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PeeHaa/gydZV/) for an example.

The fact that you think the style is overwritten by the user-agent is that the user-agent doesn't recognize the style you are trying to use (because it is invalid).

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:none` instead

Alternatively use `visibility: hidden` or `opacity: 0` but please not browser support is sketchy